# Select Count(*) increased from <30s to ~8 minutes on postgres Database - 391K Rows

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I have a relatively small database that consists of 12 tables. 3 tables serve the majority content on one of my websites. Approximately 24 hours ago I ran a small script that would do nothing more than update/delete some rows (~10k) in these tables in quick sucession. This was a script that I had run before plenty of times and is just something I use to clean up unnecessary content within this table. After about an hour of running this script I was and still am hit with an unnecessarily high amount of request timeouts from heroku. Since I had not touched anything with the project specifically I concluded that something must be going on with the database. I then proceeded to kill all open database connections and found that the timeouts stopped. Again after 10 minutes or so timeouts would start again. Looking at the queries being executed I saw that everytime that timeouts would happen is when there were 4-5 long running queries. All of these queries are either

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE private=false
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE private=FALSE LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1XXXXX
```

If left untouched these queries take approximately 8 minutes to execute!

What I am wondering is what has happened that all of a sudden doing count(*) on ~391k rows will take 8 minutes?

Things I have done:

```
Vaccum/Analyze on all tables in the database
SET statement_timeout='120s' # this seems to fix the timeouts but doesn't explain what happened
Reindexed Table
```

Some statistics on the table:

```
Table Size: 2912 MB
TOAST Size: 123 MB
Indexes Size: 31 MB
hitrate: 50%
total_read = 4217 MB
total_miss = 2076 MB
```

Results after running
"EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE private=false"

http://gyazo.com/3c9ef2caa5ccd0ce523dd8ef4cfbf733

Result after running "EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM mytable"
http://gyazo.com/510ce6c644d9a9dda197e5e3e154624c

Output to "\d question"

http://pastebin.com/WAPecWdw

Comment: Please show output of `\d question` in `psql`.

Comment: ok, I'll add that to bottom of the op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you really need a partial index like:

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_id_nonprivate ON question(id) WHERE (private = false)
```

*(Note that I originally wrote `(NOT private)` but, per the comments, that's not quite the same thing.)*

You may find it more useful to create the index as a non-unique secondary index on one or more other columns in order to permit index-only scans on that set of columns. No way to say without more info.

It's likely that PostgreSQL isn't choosing to use your index because it thinks the proportion of `private = false` rows are such that it'd be more efficient to just do a sequential scan. It can't do an index-only scan if there's no suitable index with `private` as the first column.

Update after edits: Yep, there's no suitable index. Add one like the above, or depending on query patterns possibly a secondary index on one or more other columns that's partial on `NOT private`.

You should probably also make `private` `NOT NULL` unless you actually use null in that boolean column.

Comment: add a copy of the table definition to my post.

Comment: Will adding an index for private also speed up SELECT count(*) FROM mytable because that query is just as long?

Comment: @ark `SELECT count(*) FROM mytable;` shouldn't take that long given it's doing an index-only scan on the `PRIMARY KEY`. If it does, you might have index bloat issues (consider `REINDEX`ing) or issues with the underlying hardware (consider creating and switching to a follower).

Comment: I included the explain analyze for SELECT count(*) at the bottom of my post and that query actually took longer. I already reindexed. I thought it might be issues with the hardware but it's wierd that it would just happen so sudden out of nowhere.

Comment: @ark It's using a sensible and optimal query plan, so if there's no index bloat then it's pretty much got to be hardware (or load). Try `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to see what the `shared_buffers` cache hit rate is like.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Quick question, is there any difference between your partial index and "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_nonprivate ON question (id) WHERE private=false"

Comment: @ark Actually, yes, two differences. First, since your column is nullable, `= false` is only true when `private` is false (not null), wheras `NOT private` is true if it's false *or* null. Second, even if the column were `NOT NULL`, the query planner isn't very smart about matching predicates, so it might not use an index on `NOT private` for `private = false`. Better to use `private = false`, you're right.